# send string as XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have to send a string formatted as XML to a web service as an XML document. What is the best way to turn my string

```
 $input_xml = "
<WEB>
<header>
<WebSiteID>WGI</WebSiteID>
<WebDocNumber>Doc10</WebDocNumber>
<OrderCaptureDateTime>10/07/2013</OrderCaptureDateTime>
</header>
<item>
<ItemNumber>FG-00087</ItemNumber>
<ReplacementItem></ReplacementItem>
<Quantity>2</Quantity>
<UnitPrice>6.31</UnitPrice>
<SalesTaxCode></SalesTaxCode>
<SalesTaxAmt>0</SalesTaxAmt>
</item>
</WEB>";
```

I was using `$xmlget = simplexml_load_string($input_xml);` and just sending `$xmlget` to the SOAP application.

```
$requestParams = array(
    'XMLDocNumber' => 'Test_Doc',
    'InboundXML' =>  $xmlget,
    'sStatus' =>''
);
```

The receiver of the data is say the XML is not in the "Correct Format" I am not sure which end the issue is stemming from but I thought i would ask for help.

**EDIT**

Based on the answers I got below I am now just sending the string of XML data. But now I am getting the following error from the SOAP application

```
stdClass Object ( [InboundApprovedXMLResult] => [sStatus] => Invalid XML Header Format;
```

I even added the XML header to my string so now it begins with this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your service description (WSDL) but I guess it should be:

```
$requestParams = array(
    'XMLDocNumber' => 'Test_Doc',
    'InboundXML' =>  $input_xml,
    'sStatus' =>''
);
```

Passing a simple_xml_element makes no sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

[`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) loads the XML string and returns an object, but you should be sending the *actual* string instead.

Change your code to:

```
$requestParams = array(
    'XMLDocNumber' => 'Test_Doc',
    'InboundXML' =>  $input_xml,
    'sStatus' =>''
);
```

Comment: @Denoteone: Remove the extra space from the beginning. It's better to use the HEREDOC syntax: [example](http://pastebin.com/DWawm7Uf)